# Direction of inequality

Tags: real-analysis

I have an expression that looks like the following.

$\sqrt{a^2*(1-cos{\theta})+b^2-ab\sin{\theta}}$

for $\theta \in [0, \pi]$. I know that $a \leq \epsilon b$. When I substitute this inequality I get

$b\sqrt{\epsilon^2*(1-cos{\theta})+1-\epsilon\sin{\theta}}$

How do I know if this quantity is $\geq$ or $\leq$ the original expression? If every operation in the expression was a $+$ then it follows that the resulting expression is an upper bound, but in this case I have both a $+$ and a $-$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  a^2(1-\cos \theta)-ab\sin \theta+b^2 &=
  a^2+b^2-a(a\cos \theta+b\sin \theta) \\
  &= a^2+b^2-a\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin (\theta+\phi) \\
  \sin \phi &= \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \\
  \cos \phi &= \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
\end{align*}

> $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2-|a|\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
> \le \sqrt{a^2(1-\cos \theta)-ab\sin \theta+b^2}
> \le \sqrt{a^2+b^2+|a|\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$